Problemas al desplegar en ninjahosting
estoy intentando desplegar una aplicación, primeramente estoy subiendo el backend (nestjs y prisma), he tenido una especie de errores que no me permiten lanzar la aplicacion. Los pasos que sigo son:

Generar el build
Zipear dist, package.json y el archivo .env
Subir el zip al servidor y descomprimirlo.

Luego voy al setup node.js App, donde configuro las rutas para que reconozca la carpeta en la cual dejé lo extraido. Al momento de ejecutar el npm install (el plugin Setup Node.js App tiene un boton para ejecutar) corre por unos minutos, es cuando al final me sale un cuadro de "Error" sin ningun mensaje añadido.
No sé si es un tema de versiones de node, probé en local con esa versión que permite el servidor (20.12.2) y no tuve problemas con la instalación de dependencias y ejecución.
Quiero poder desplegar la aplicación debido a que estoy en práctica/pasantía, he intentado de varias maneras desplegar el backend pero sin éxito. Podría cambiar de hostin sin embargo es una decisión que no está en mis manos en estos momentos.
